# \acl{} command problem while using glossaries-extra with bib2gls

Tags: glossaries-extra, bib2gls

The following exemplary document compiles as intended in **example 1**.

**Example 1:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[record,acronym,toc,shortcuts=ac]{glossaries-extra}

\usepackage{relsize} % required for new abbreviation Style long-short-sm
\setabbreviationstyle[\acronymtype]{long-short-sm}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
    src={entries},
    sort={en-GB}
]

\begin{document}
    Test 1: \ac{se}. % or \cgls{se} % WORKS
    Test 2: \acl{se}. % or \glsxtrlong{se} % WORKS ONLY IF \ac{se} (Test 1) UNCOMMENTED
    \printunsrtglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of~acronyms},style=index]
\end{document}
```

[image: Proper result.]

However, when `\ac{se}` (or `\cgls{se}`) command is commented out, the result throws a warning – probably caused by command `\acl{se}` (`\glsxtrlong{se}`) being overlooked by `bib2gls` or pdfLaTeX – in **example 2**.

**Example 2:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[record,acronym,toc,shortcuts=ac]{glossaries-extra}

\usepackage{relsize} % required for new abbreviation Style long-short-sm
\setabbreviationstyle[\acronymtype]{long-short-sm}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
    src={entries},
    sort={en-GB}
]

\begin{document}
    Test 1: %\ac{se}. % or \cgls{se} % WORKS
    Test 2: \acl{se}. % or \glsxtrlong{se} % WORKS ONLY IF \ac{se} (Test 1) UNCOMMENTED
    \printunsrtglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of~acronyms},style=index]
\end{document}
```

> Package glossaries-extra Warning: Glossary entry `se' has not been defined on input line 15.

[image: Improper result.]

The content of `entries.bib` file used by the `bib2gls` application is attached below.

**entries.bib:**

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@acronym{se,
  long      = {some example},
  short     = {SE},
  timestamp = {31.03.2018}
}
```

Can **example 2** be modified or fixed to work while still using only the `\acl{se}` (`\glsxtrlong{se}`) command – without prior usage of, e.g., `\ac{se}` (`\cgls{se}`)?

---

EDIT #2: A complete reinstallation of MikTeX solved the problem.

EDIT:
Despite updating to version 1.32 of `glossaries-extra` the error persists.

**Not working with `bib2gls`:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[record,acronym]{glossaries-extra}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{entries.bib}
    @acronym{se,
        long  = {some example},
        short = {SE}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={entries}]

\begin{document}
    %Test 1: \gls{se}.\\
    Test 2: \glsxtrlong{se}.
    \printunsrtglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\end{document}
```

[image: Acronym `se' undefined]

> Package glossaries-extra Warning: Glossary entry `se' has not been defined on input line 17.
>   Package glossaries-extra Warning: No entries defined in glossary `acronym' on input line 18.

Uncommenting `%Test 1: …` line or adding `\glsadd{se}` to preamble is a workaround, but still does not fix the core problem.

**Working without `bib2gls`:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[record,acronym]{glossaries-extra}

\newacronym{se}{SE}{some example}

\begin{document}
    %Test 1: \gls{se}.\\
    Test 2: \glsxtrlong{se}.
    \printunsrtglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\end{document}
```

[image: Acronym `se' defined]

Comment: You can use `\glsadd{se}` in your preamble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in earlier versions of `glossaries-extra` that meant that commands like `\glsxtrlong` weren't writing the record to the `.aux` file correctly. This was fixed in version 1.30, so make sure you have the latest version.